# Lorentz transformations for scalar fields in QFT --- Peskin and Schroder

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lorentz-symmetry

I'm struggling to understand the following logic from Peskin and Schroeder, page 23:

The book defines
$$ |\vec{p} \rangle = \sqrt{2E_p} a^\dagger_p |0 \rangle $$
so that the inner product $\langle \vec{p}| \vec{q}\rangle$ is a Lorentz invariant object. It then says that this above equation, which is a 'normalization condition', implies that
$$ U(\Lambda) |\vec{p}\rangle = | \Lambda \vec{p} \rangle$$
or, if we prefer to think of this transformation as acting on the operator $a^\dagger_p$, we can write
$$ U(\Lambda) a^\dagger_p U^{-1}(\Lambda) = \sqrt{\frac{E_{\Lambda p}}{E_p}} a^\dagger_{\Lambda \vec{p}} $$
I don't understand how these two equations are arrived at. The book seems to suggest that it's obvious, but clearly I'm missing something. Thanks.

Comment: I can't answer, but a slightly more intuitive (at least to me) derivation of the transformation law for the creation operator can be obtained from requiring that the scalar field $\phi(x)$ transform as $\phi(x)\rightarrow \phi'(x')=U^{-1}(\Lambda)\phi(x')U(\Lambda)=\phi(x)$. Then the transformation law for the creation operator you've given is the only transformation law compatible with Lorentz Invariance. From this transformation law we can then deduce that the normalization $|p\rangle=\sqrt{2E_p}a^\dagger |0\rangle$ gives a Lorentz invariant scalar product $\langle q|p\rangle$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**The first statement**

$| p \rangle$ is an eigenstate of $\hat{P}^{\mu}$ operators with eigenvalue $p^{\mu}$. It's natural then that 
$$
U(\Lambda )| p \rangle
$$
is also eigenstate of $\hat{P}^{\mu}$:
$$
\hat{P}^{\mu}U(\Lambda )| p \rangle = U(\Lambda )\left[ U(\Lambda^{-1})\hat{P}^{\mu}U(\Lambda )\right]| p \rangle = U(\Lambda )\Lambda^{\mu}_{\ \nu}\hat{P}^{\nu}| p \rangle = \Lambda^{\mu}_{\ \nu}p^{\nu}U(\Lambda )| p \rangle .
$$
In general (for non-scalar case when $| p \rangle = | p ,\sigma \rangle$) from this follows that 
$$
U(\Lambda )| p, \sigma  \rangle = \sum_{\sigma {'}}C_{\sigma {'} \sigma}| \Lambda p, \sigma {'}\rangle 
$$
and for all states $| p, \sigma \rangle $ states $U(\Lambda )| p, \sigma \rangle$ also belongs to the Hilbert space of eigenstates, so if in the beginning $| p, \sigma \rangle $ belongs to some definite orbit of the Lorentz group, then $U(\Lambda )| p, \sigma \rangle$ will also belong to this orbit: 
$$
| p, \sigma \rangle = |\mathbf p , \sigma \rangle_{p_{0} = f(\mathbf p , m)} \Rightarrow U(\Lambda )| p, \sigma \rangle = \sum_{\sigma {'}}C_{\sigma {'} \sigma}| \mathbf {\Lambda p}, \sigma {'}\rangle_{p_{0} = f(\mathbf p , m)}.
$$
**The invariance condition** of $\langle p | q \rangle $ (since $\langle p| q\rangle = C(p) \delta (\mathbf p - \mathbf q) $ lorentz-invariance condition means that $C(p) \sim E_{p})$ means that $C_{\sigma \sigma {'}}$ satisfies $C_{\sigma \sigma{''}}C^{\dagger}_{\sigma {''}\sigma{'}} = \delta_{\sigma \sigma {'}}$. In simplest scalar case this directly leads to
$$
\tag 1 U(\Lambda )| \mathbf p \rangle = e^{i\alpha}| \mathbf {U(\Lambda ) p}\rangle ,
$$
where $\alpha$ is some parameter of transformation given by $\Lambda$. It can be set to zero.

**The second statement**

It automatically follows from the first statement (given by eq. $(1)$) if we use definition
$$
| \mathbf p \rangle = \sqrt{2E_{p}}a^{\dagger}(\mathbf p) | \rangle 
$$
and eq. $(1)$, we'll get
$$
U(\Lambda )| \mathbf p \rangle = U(\Lambda )\left[\sqrt{2E_{p}} a^{\dagger}(\mathbf p)|\rangle\right] = \sqrt{2E_{p}}[U(\Lambda )\hat{a}^{\dagger}(\mathbf p)U^{-1}(\Lambda) ]U(\Lambda ) | \rangle = 
$$
$$
= \left| U(\Lambda ) | \rangle = | \rangle \right| = \sqrt{2E_{p}}[U(\Lambda )\hat{a}^{\dagger}(\mathbf p)U^{-1}(\Lambda) ] | \rangle = \sqrt{2E_{\Lambda p}}\hat{a}^{\dagger}(\mathbf {\Lambda p })| \rangle \Rightarrow
$$
$$
U(\Lambda )\hat{a}^{\dagger}(\mathbf p)U^{-1}(\Lambda) = \sqrt{\frac{E_{\Lambda p}}{E_{p}}}\hat{a}^{\dagger}(\mathbf {\Lambda p }).
$$

Comment: Clearly *completely* obvious.

Comment: @theage : what did you mean?

Comment: @Andrew McAddams : Is the invariance of the vacuum $U(\Lambda)|0\rangle=|0\rangle$ an assumption, or can it be proved?

Comment: @StephenBlake : formally it is postulate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer --- I'm lead to ask, though, where the result
$$ U(\Lambda^{-1}) P^\mu U(\Lambda) = \Lambda^\mu{}_\nu P^\nu$$
comes from?

Comment: @gj255 : it is formal result as the consequence of the Poincare group algebra. If you need the derivation, I'll add it into the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure I know how to derive this, so a derivation would be great... If you could point me in the direction of one on the web to save you the trouble of writing it out, that would work perfectly also!

Comment: @gj255 : it seems that Weinberg's QFT Vol. 1 contains derivarion you've asked.

Comment: @StephenBlake: That's a physical input. If the state called "vacuum" wasn't invariant under Poincare transformations (among them Lorentz transformations), then we'd notice all kinds of wacky effects like non-conservation of momentum and/or angular momentum. To avoid such behaviour, the vacuum state better be homogeneous, isotropic and boost-invariant.

Comment: Your vacuum kets lack $0$ labels.