# Lorentz transformation representation confusion for fields in Peskin & Schroeder

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, inertial-frames, representation-theory

I have a simple question, I probably misunderstood some minor thing, because this should be trivial.
My question is regarding the book **Peskin & Schroeder** 1995 **Introduction to Quantum Field Theory**, at **page 59**.

#### Question briefly

It seems to me, that there is a contradiction between (3.106) and (3.110). Let's say in coordinate system $A$ I have a vector $p$, and in coordinate system $B$ the same vector looks like $\Lambda p$, then a field should be transformed as $U(\Lambda)\psi(x)U^{-1}(\Lambda) = R(\Lambda) \psi(\Lambda^{-1}x)$, not as in the book $R(\Lambda^{-1}) \psi(\Lambda x)$.

#### Question detailed

In Peskin & Schroeder 1995 Introduction to Quantum Field Theory, at page 59 (3.106), it says, that
$$
\tag{3.106}
|\mathbf{p}, s \rangle = \sqrt{2 E_\mathbf{p}} a_\mathbf{p}^{s \dagger} |0\rangle.
$$

Now, according to the book, if we look this in an other coordinate system, this state will look like $|\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{p}, s \rangle$. And so, we can derive, that

$$
\tag{3.109}
U(\Lambda) a_\mathbf{p}^{s} U^{-1}(\Lambda) = \frac{E_{\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{p}}} {E_{\mathbf{p}}} a_{\mathbf{\Lambda}a_\mathbf{p}}^{s}.
$$

Now, our convention here was that that any vector will look like in that other system as $v' = \Lambda v$. Let's say I have a scalar field $\phi(x)$, this looks like $\phi(\Lambda^{-1}x)$ in the other coordinate system. The same applies to the fermion field, this should be transformed as

$$
U(\Lambda)\psi(x)U^{-1}(\Lambda) = R(\Lambda) \psi(\Lambda^{-1}x),
$$

but in the book it's quiet the opposite, it says there,

$$
\tag{3.110}
U(\Lambda)\psi(x)U^{-1}(\Lambda) = R(\Lambda^{-1}) \psi(\Lambda x).
$$

What am I missing?

Related: [Lorentz transformations for scalar fields in QFT --- Peskin and Schroder](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/154673/)

Comment: The point is P&S defined $\Lambda | p \rangle = | \Lambda p \rangle$. If they did it as  $|\Lambda  p \rangle = | \Lambda^{-1} p \rangle$, then your assumption is correct. Both of the two ways work correctly and it is just a conventional problem I think.

Answer (score 1):

One can check these kind of formulae by seeing if they respect the goup property. If
$$
U(\Lambda)_1\psi U(\Lambda_1)^{-1}= R(\Lambda_1^{-1})\psi
$$
then
$$
U(\Lambda_2)U(\Lambda)_1\psi U(\Lambda_1)^{-1}U(\Lambda_2)^{-1}= U(\Lambda_2)R(\Lambda_1^{-1})\psi U(\Lambda_2)^{-1}\\
= R(\Lambda_1^{-1}) U(\Lambda_2) \psi U(\Lambda_2)^{-1}\\ \hbox{(operators $U$ commute with arrays of numbers $R$)}\\
= R(\Lambda_1^{-1})R(\Lambda_2^{-1})\psi\\
= R(\Lambda_1^{-1}\Lambda_2^{-1})\psi\\
= R((\Lambda_2 \Lambda_1)^{-1})\psi
$$
which is coincides with the action of
$$
U(\Lambda_2)U(\Lambda_1)=U(\Lambda_2\Lambda_1).
$$
So P&S are correct. Your formula would lead to the R"s being backwards. (I did not look at the \Lambda x), but you can check this too.

Note that the *wavefunction* corresponding to  a state $|{\bf p}\rangle$ is
$$
\phi_{\bf p}(x) = \langle 0|\psi(x)|{\bf p}\rangle
$$
so that the wavefunction for $U(\Lambda) |{\bf p}\rangle$ is
$$
\langle 0|\psi(x)U(\Lambda)|{\bf p}\rangle\\
= \langle 0|U(\Lambda)U(\Lambda)^{-1}\psi(x)
U(\Lambda)|{\bf p}\rangle\\
= \langle 0|U(\Lambda)^{-1}\psi(x)U(\Lambda)|{\bf p}\rangle
$$

which has  the $\Lambda$'s inverted as you want them to be.

Comment: Aha, this is interesting. I know, that P&S are correct, I just don't really understand why. I would like to reconcile the two operations that I presented. It doesn't have to be QFT. A classical vector field transforms as $f(x) \rightarrow \Lambda f(\Lambda^{-1} x)$, if for example a solution to a plane wave solution transforms as $exp(-ixp) \rightarrow exp(-i \Lambda p x)$. I will think about it more, you answer is an other good insight.

Comment: I've added a bit more that might help.